# Error Sub Main es declarado más de una vez visual basic

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

Hola siempre obtengo este error:

> 'Sub Main' is declared more than once in 'server':
>   server.My.MyApplication.Main(Args() As String), server.Program.Main()
>   (BC30738)

La captura del error:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Alguna forma de solucionarlo?

El error aparece cuando compilo un programa de consola en forma de formulario porque no quiero que me muestre mi consola. Cuando lo hago con visual studio no tengo ningún problema. Añadí la referencia a system.windows.form ya que funcionará como formulario pero supongo que también tendre que incluir algo más para que funcione como un formulario.

Comment: Probaste con buscar la palabra "Sub Main" y ver qué resultados te da?

Comment: Indicarme más detalles. El problema puede ser resultado compilandose en visual studio. Supongo que será porque cuando compilo mi programa de consola como formulario además de añadirle la referencia a system.windows.forms tenga que incluirlealgo más, de todos modos voy a dar más detalles sin embargo en visual studio no da ningún problema.

Comment: y el formulario donde lo armaste? No es lo mismo un proyecto de windows form que de consola...

Comment: es una aplicación de consola que compile como windows application (formulario) para que no me la muestre pero para que funcione hay que añadirle se supone simplemente la referencia a system.windows.form eso pensaba yo, sin embargo un programa de consola  puede ser compilado en visual studio por lo que supongo tenga que hacer más modificaciones en mi proyecto. El formulario no lo cree, pero entonces porque cuando compilo en visual studio un programa de consola en forma de formulario no pasa nada¿? A lo mejor mi ide no incluye la configuracion del mismo¿?

Comment: Si queres un fomulario crea un proyecto windows forms. Lo que cambia no es solo una referencia.